# How to inject callback classes in Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, callback

Is it possible to use callbacks with `Spring` to that they are managed by application context?

My problem is when a `service` is used from outer by `@Autowired`, but within that service there is a callback defined using `new` operator.

The following example executes a method that is worth retrying. Spring offers a `RetryCallback` for this case (I know this could be acchieved differently, but just to illustrate my callback problem).

```
@Service
class MyService {

    //main method invoked
    void run(DataVO dataVO) {
        //new operator not usable in spring context
        RetryCallback<Object> retryCallback = new RetryCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
                return createBooking(dataVO);
            }
        };
    }

    private Object createBooking(DataVO dataVO) {
        //creates the booking, worth retry on specific failures
            //uses further injected/autowired services here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to refactor this snippet so that the callback is managed by spring/injected/autowired?

Answer (score 1):

Make your service implement the callback interface :

```
@Service
class MyService implements RetryCallback<Object> {

    //main method invoked
    void run(DataVO dataVO) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
        return createBooking(dataVO);
    }

    private Object createBooking(DataVO dataVO) {
        //creates the booking, worth retry on specific failures
            //uses further injected/autowired services here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible: a `@Service` is a stateless singleton. Therefore I would have to pass `DataVO` in the constructor and save it to a local field, otherwise the retry method from `RetryCallback` could not use it. This again is only possible in stateful services.